# Election banner down on main site page

Tags: support, status-completed, election

The election banner is not visible on the main math.SE site page (although it is visible on this meta site).  For me at least, this has been the case for at least the last 13 hours or so.

Is this intentional?

**Added**: It is happening again in the nomination phase of the 2011 election.

Comment: It's been going on and off the past few days: one day the banner's there, the next day it's gone. I'm not seeing any point in the banner not being displayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Update:

The system message has been restored.

*[original message]*

---

As far as I can determine, this was likely unintentional. I am looking into it right now and I will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

From [2011 Community Moderator Election](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2307/2011-community-moderator-election):

> @Rebecca, I don't see the banner
>   announcing the election on the main
>   site (it seems to have happened
>   before) - is it intentional? – Zev
>   Chonoles
>
> @zev the announcement banner lasts two
>   days, as with all site banners -- if
>   it appears too often, it gets ignored.
>   This post is featured so it will
>   appear on the main site all the time
>   in the sidebar. – Jeff Atwood♦

Comment: We may add it back again if we feel it is truly needed, but we do try to keep it to a minimum so that people don't get into the habit of ignoring the system messages.